# Showing a PDF with its URL using Web View

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent, webview, androidpdfviewer

I have a URL for my PDF and I want to show it in browser . I was using `Intent` but the PDF was download not Viewed , so I searched for this thing and I fount that , I can use this link before my PDF's URL `"https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url="`  .

It was working but yesterday it's not working and it shows `Couldn't preview file there was a problem showing this image` I searched for this thing also and I found something like it is a bug in Google drive .
Is there any simple way to show a PDF with its URL in browser without downloading it ?

here is my code

```
  Dialog dialog = new Dialog(requireActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
                                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                                dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

                                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.webview_layout);
                                WebView webView = dialog.findViewById(R.id.webview);
                                ProgressBar progressBar = dialog.findViewById(R.id.pp);
                                dialog.show();

                                String path = caseSummaryModelResource.data.getURLWithParamter();

                                webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
                                webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                                webView.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                                    webView.setRendererPriorityPolicy(WebView.RENDERER_PRIORITY_IMPORTANT, false);
                                }

                                String url = "https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + path;
                                webView.loadUrl(url);
                                //webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
                                //webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                                webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                                    @Override
                                    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                                        view.loadUrl(url);
                                        return true;
                                    }

                                    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                                        Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                                        //super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                                        if (view.getTitle().equals("")) {
                                            view.reload();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                                webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                                    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                                        if (progress < 100) {
                                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        }
                                        if (progress == 100) {
                                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
```

Comment: `have a URL for my PDF` Please show how it looks like. The value for 'path'.

Comment: It is private I can't show it in public but make sure when I put it n the browser , it works

Comment: You do not have to tell the url. I asked you how it looks like. Thats all

Comment: http://IP/x/x/x/x/?x=12&x=12&x=12&x=

Comment: That can never work without a protocoll.

Comment: it was working already . Before the URL of course https